# Set color column not working on VIM

Tags: vim

I've just installed `vim` to my home directory on a Webfaction shared server. Everthing appears to be working well, except the one feature I installed an updated version for - set color column.

When I do the following:

```
:set cc=80
```

The command remains at the prompt and nothing happens. Any ideas?

**`:version` output:**

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  8 2014 09:05:26)
Compiled by ryanjdillon@web394.webfaction.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic          +diff            +jumplist        -mouse_sysmouse  +scrollbind      +virtualedit
+autocmd         +digraphs        -keymap          -mouse_urxvt     +signs           +visual
-balloon_eval    -dnd             -langmap         +mouse_xterm     +smartindent     +visualextra
-browse          -ebcdic          +libcall         +multi_byte      -sniff           +viminfo
+builtin_terms   -emacs_tags      +linebreak       +multi_lang      +startuptime     +vreplace
+byte_offset     +eval            +lispindent      -mzscheme        +statusline      +wildignore
+cindent         +ex_extra        +listcmds        +netbeans_intg   -sun_workshop    +wildmenu
+clientserver    +extra_search    +localmap        +path_extra      +syntax          +windows
+clipboard       -farsi           -lua             -perl            +tag_binary      +writebackup
+cmdline_compl   +file_in_path    +menu            +persistent_undo +tag_old_static  +X11
+cmdline_hist    +find_in_path    +mksession       +postscript      -tag_any_white   +xfontset
+cmdline_info    +float           +modify_fname    +printer         -tcl             -xim
+comments        +folding         +mouse           -profile         +terminfo        +xsmp_interact
-conceal         -footer          -mouseshape      -python          +termresponse    +xterm_clipboard
+cryptv          +fork()          -mouse_dec       -python3         +textobjects     -xterm_save
-cscope          +gettext         -mouse_gpm       +quickfix        +title
+cursorbind      -hangul_input    -mouse_jsbterm   +reltime         -toolbar
+cursorshape     +iconv           -mouse_netterm   -rightleft       +user_commands
+dialog_con      +insert_expand   -mouse_sgr       -ruby            +vertsplit
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/home/ryanjdillon/share/vim"
Compilation:
gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lI
CE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux
```

**`:echo $VIMRUNTIME` output:**

```
/home/ryanjdillon/share/vim/vim74
```

Comment: Is there any visible highlighting on `:hi ColorColumn`?!

Comment: I get `E411: highlight group not found: ColorColumn?!`

Comment: That's strange. Does it work when you define it, e.g. `:hi ColorColumn term=reverse ctermbg=12 guibg=LightRed`?!

Comment: it even let me execute it. it just sits there like ``set cc=80`` does. Think the angelo may be write here. Haven't tried re-compiling yet.

Comment: So, how did you compile Vim (with syntax support)? What's the full output of `:version`?

Comment: i didn't deliberately, but it appears to be there

Comment: BTW, as long as there's no error message, commands like `:set` and `:hi` **are executed**. The command line is just not cleared in Vim.

Comment: @shootingstars The command is `:hi ColorColumn`, `?!` is not part of the command given by @IngoKarkat.

Comment: I was in fact entering that. That may have been my problem. Derp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ingo Karkat's first question (in the comments) and your answer are very helpful.

I am pretty sure that you compiled vim but did not install the runtime files.  The ColorColumn highlight group (and lots of others) are defined in `syntax/syntax.vim` under the runtime directory.

Looking at your `:version` information, I think that the runtime directory should be `/home/ryanjdillon/share/vim/runtime/`.  You should be able to confirm (unless this is also broken) with

```
 :echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

Does that directory exist?  If so, does it contain the `syntax/` subdirectory and `syntax/syntax.vim`?  I doubt it.

Reread the installation instructions, and download the runtime files.

Comment: My `VIMRUNTIME` is `/home/ryanjdillon/share/vim/vim74`, which does contain `syntax/syntax.vim`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Strange... it is working now. Not sure what happened. Is there a protocol for selecting an answer (or not) in a scenario like this?